# phonegap - single html will really work for all platforms?

Tags: cordova

i'm thinking of starting development with phonegap, and i was wondering if a single html basecode will work for all platforms?

Aside from that, im assuming i'd have to have the platform-correspondent cordova.js in each of the projects folders, and my calls to the api in the html would just remain the same , correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you are correct. you'll still have to use the specific folder tree and tools for preparing to different platforms (like installing the android dev tools, eclipse plugins etc for android, xcode for iphone, etc), but the html+js stays the same. phone gap takes care of the bridge between js to the local api (a jave jar in android  for example) 
or you can use the cloud compiling to get compiling done. I had good experience with it